# NullPointerException w/ Sound Class

Tags: java, audio

I am currently building a game engine and inside of the engine there is a class, called Sound.java. The purpose of this class is to load sound effects into the engine and play them. 
The problem is that inside the constructor of Sound.java, it's throwing an exception called, NullPointerException; however, this doesn't make any sense as I am referencing to the correct file path of the said sound file.

Take a look at the below code + stack trace and please help me figure this out!

**Sound.java**:

```
public class Sound {
private Clip clip; 

public Sound(String filePath) { 
    try {
        System.out.println(filePath);
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream(filePath));
        AudioFormat baseFormat = ais.getFormat();
        AudioFormat decodeFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, baseFormat.getSampleRate(), 16, baseFormat.getChannels(), baseFormat.getChannels() * 2, baseFormat.getSampleRate(), false);
        AudioInputStream dais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodeFormat, ais);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(dais);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        CEDebug.showDebugMessage("Sound File Not Found");
    }
}
```

**CESound.java**:

```
public class CESound {

private static Map<String, Sound> soundMap = new HashMap<String, Sound>(); //Sound Effects HashMap

/**
 * Adds a new sound into the hash map<br>
 * The file must be <strong>.wav</strong> format
 * @param key the key or ID that will be used to access this sound effect
 * @param fileName the name of the sound file
 */
public static void addSound(String key, String fileName) {
    try {
        soundMap.put(key, new Sound(ReferenceLibrary.SoundLocation + fileName)); //Error: (3/4/15) Sound File Not Found!
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        CEDebug.showDebugMessage("Sound File Not Found");
    }
}
```

**ReferenceLibrary.java**:

```
public class ReferenceLibrary {
   public static final String ResourceLocation = "./Resources/";
   public static final String SoundLocation = ResourceLocation + "Audio/Sound/";
}
```

**Stack Trace**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(SoftMidiAudioFileReader.java:130)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1113)
at CoreEngine.ResourceLibrary.Other.Sound.<init>(Sound.java:16)
at CoreEngine.ResourceLibrary.CESound.addSound(CESound.java:21)
at ResourceLibrary.ResourceLoader.loadSounds(ResourceLoader.java:48)
at GameStates.MenuState.init(MenuState.java:25)
at GameStates.MenuState.<init>(MenuState.java:21)
at GameStates.GameStateManager.loadState(GameStateManager.java:27)
at GameStates.GameStateManager.<init>(GameStateManager.java:22)
at GameEngine.Core.init(Core.java:29)
at CoreEngine.GameEngine.CoreEngine.<init>(CoreEngine.java:55)
at GameEngine.Core.<init>(Core.java:24)
at GameEngine.Core.main(Core.java:62)
```

Thanks!

-Nick

Comment: looks like `(ReferenceLibrary.SoundLocation + fileName)` having some problem it means  AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream is not creating instance properly. are you sure this line is not giving any exception `AudioFormat baseFormat = ais.getFormat();`

Comment: What code line is the error message refering to? And why is there a reference to com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream? Everything you need should be coming from java.sound.sampled library. I think the sun.media.sound stuff has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Consider using TinySound (on github). Free, easy to use, pretty small, basic library.

(2) I'd recommend this way (from javax.sound.sampled) to get the sound data:
[AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(URL)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream(java.net.URL))

or used the form

```
AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(File)
```

To do this, first define the URL or File. Added benefit, it will be easier to debug/verify whether you have actually made contact with the file prior to creating the AudioInputStream.